# Show that E is a finite extension of F

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Given that E is a field extension of a field F, and E is a splitting field of F of some nonconstant polynomial $f(x) \in F[x]$ .

How do I show that E is a finite extension of F?

Comment: The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_field#The_construction) gives a construction that is evidently finite, and even gives a bound for $[E:F]$.

Answer (score 2):

$f$ has finitely many zeros $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ in $E$. Then
$E=F(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$. Then each extension
$F(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k)/F(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{k-1})$
is simple and generated by an algebraic element, so is finite. As
$F(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)/F$ is a finite tower of finite extensions,
it is also finite.